# jq substring gives "jq: error: Cannot index string with object"

Tags: parsing, substring, jq

### Problem

I'm trying to filter a [json JQ](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) result to only show a substring of the original string. For example if a JQ filter grabed the value

```
4ffceab674ea8bb5ec421c612536696839bbaccecf64e851dfc270d795ee55d1
```

I want it to only return the first 10 characters `4ffceab674`.

---

### What I've tried

On the [Official JQ website](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example3) you can find an example that should give me what I need:

```
Command:    jq '.[2:4]'

Input:      "abcdefghi"
Output:     "cd"
```

I've tried to test this out with a simple example in the unix terminal:

```
# this works fine, => "abcdefghi"
echo '"abcdefghi"' | jq '.'

# this doesn't work => jq: error: Cannot index string with object
echo '"abcdefghi"' | jq '.[2:4]'
```

Comment: Also: jq version is 1.3, I'm running in ubuntu trusty.

Comment: Also: just realized other basic filters do not work such as 'implode', 'explode', 'split'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out most of these filters are not yet in the released version. For reference see issue [#289](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/289)

What you could do is download the latest development version and compile from source. See [download page](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) > From source on Linux

After that, if indexing still doesn't work for strings, you should, at least, be able to do explode, index, implode combination, which seems to have been your plan.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer -- although I wasn't able to install the new version to confirm that the substring command works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [jq-1.3 manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.3/) I suspect there isn't a solution using that version since it offers no primitives for extacting parts of a string.